# Multiple Scarlet callbacks after toggle between onStart and onPause

Tags: android, websocket, singleton, android-lifecycle, koin

By using Kotlin i created a networkModule, code below

```
val networkModule = module {

   ......

single {
        return@single AndroidLifecycle.ofApplicationForeground(androidApplication())
    }

// Scarlet WebSocket library for Tinder
    single {
        return@single Scarlet.Builder()
            .webSocketFactory(get<OkHttpClient>().newWebSocketFactory(Wss))
            .lifecycle(get())  // I can create my own lifeCycle and combineWith(), for example accounts.isEmpty
            .backoffStrategy(LinearBackoffStrategy(5000))
            .addMessageAdapterFactory(GsonMessageAdapter.Factory(get()))
            .addStreamAdapterFactory(CoroutinesStreamAdapterFactory())
            .build()
            .create(FlowSocketApi::class.java)
    }
}
val lifecycleModule = module {
    single {
        return@single AppLifeCycleObserver()
    }
}
```

I also have an Observer class that is registered to the Application lifecycle.

```
class AppLifeCycleObserver :
    LifecycleObserver, KoinComponent {

    private val flowEventsObserver: LiveData<WebSocket.Event> =
        flowSocketService.observeEvents().consumeAsFlow().asLiveData()

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onEnterForeground() {
        flowEventsObserver.observeForever { event ->
           when(event) {
            is WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionOpened<*> -> {
                println("WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionOpened")
                println(event)
            }
            is WebSocket.Event.OnMessageReceived -> {
                println("WebSocket.Event.OnMessageReceived")
                println(event.message.toString())

            }
            is WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionClosing -> {
                println("WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionClosing")
                println(event)
            }
            is WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionClosed -> {
                println("WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionClosed")
                println(event)
            }
            is WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionFailed -> {
                println("WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionFailed")
                println(event)
            }
        }
        }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onEnterBackground() {
        
    }
}
```

which of course is initialized in the Application class

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    private val appLifeCycleObserver: AppLifeCycleObserver by inject()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@MyApplication)
            modules(
                arrayListOf(networkModule,databaseModule,managersModule,repositoryModule,lifecycleModule)
            )
        }

        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(appLifeCycleObserver)
}
```

When the app starts, Scarlet creates a connection and onEnterForeground is triggered. So the LiveData outputs
`OnConnectionOpened(webSocket=okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket@6795837)`

After that i press the home button so the application enters background, so the Scarlet has to cancel the current socket connection. However after relaunch the app, app gets in Foreground start, Scarlet has to reopen the connection as it does but the problem is that in my Logcat i see double times the print

```
OnConnectionOpened(webSocket=okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket@b87493b)
OnConnectionOpened(webSocket=okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket@b87493b)
```

And as i go on and do the same thing the onConnectionOpened gets multiplied...!!
What is going wrong??

Comment: You seem to be adding an observer each time it comes in the foreground with `onEnterForeground`. Shouldn't you remove the observer on `onEnterBackground` ?

Answer (score 0):

@Gabiele Petrioli

```
private val flowEventsObserver: LiveData<FlowSocketResponse> =
        flowSocketService.observeEvents().consumeAsFlow().asLiveData()

private lateinit var mObserver: Observer<WebSocket.Event>
```

So onEnterForeground is like that

```
mObserver = Observer<WebSocket.Event> { it ->
       it?.let {
                flowSocketHandler.webSocketEventResolver(it)
        }
}
flowEventsObserver.observeForever(mObserver)
```

and onEnterBackground is

```
flowEventsObserver.removeObserver(mObserver)
```

However when i pause and relaunch the app i get an exception that the livedata can be observed only once or something.